# MS Bot Framework - web chat widget save chat history

Tags: botframework

I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework in both web chat & FB Messenger platforms.

I wondering if there is any easy way to **save and show the user his chat history**, even if the page was re-loaded, or if the user leave the page and come back after a while..
because right now, with the IFRAME method, every time the page is re-loaded it's kind of opening new session with the bot..

I've thought of create new api in my backend to get user chat history, but it sounds not a wise thing to do..

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is not currently possible.  We have a POC in which we achieved this but we had to modify the web chat code.  We hope to have this feature available by the end of the year, but no concrete timeline exists. There is a good conversation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/365) discussing this.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks..can I use and contribute to the POC project?

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on that

Comment: I am able to share this project with you, however, keep in mind it was just a POC

Comment: I'll update this question with a link to a GitHub Repo when I have cleaned up the solution

Answer (score 1):

Bot Framework also provides us a powerful service called [Bot Framework State service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state) which enables your bot to store and retrieve state data that is associated with a user, a conversation, or a specific user within the context of a specific conversation.

So the easiest solution we used was something like this:

1. [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state#save-state-data) any message sent by user and by bot in user's BotData
2. When user joins or asks for history, immiditaly [extract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state#get-state-data) messages from the
   BotData and send back to user by the way adding names of user and
   bot on the top of each message (for making it easier to differentiate bot's messages from user's messages)

Comment: The Bot Framework State Service API is not recommended for production environments, and may be deprecated in a future release. It is recommended that you update your bot code to use the in-memory storage for testing purposes or use one of the Azure Extensions for production bots. For more information, see the Manage state data topic for .NET or Node implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We persist the chat history with the [directline JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) features.

Each conversation has its Id. Persist the conversation Id. Pass the persisted conversation Id to the chat component initialization, and the chat initializes with the history.

Bot connection initialization. `getPersistedConversationId` reads the conversationId from the cookies

```
const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: "directline secret",
        webSocket: false,
        conversationId: getPersistedConversationId()
    });
```

initialize the webchat component with the connection

```
BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: { id: "userid", name: "username",},
    },
    window.document.getElementById('chat'));
```

subscribe to the connection status change. when connection is opened - persist the conversation id. `saveConversationId` saves the conversation id into cookies

```
botConnection.connectionStatus$
    .subscribe(function (connectionStatus){
        switch(connectionStatus){
            case 2:
                saveConversationId(botConnection.conversationId);
        }
    });
```